# Megafauna is to animals as what is to insects?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy, terminology

I'm aware of several species of "giant" insects, such as the Meganeura (giant dragonfly) and the Arthropleura (giant centipede) — but I was wondering if anyone knew of a loose term similar to *megafauna/megaflora* that described large insects... *Megainsecta*?

Comment: Insects are six-legged arthropods, so maybe you could say "mega-arthropod." (The [arthropod phylum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod) also includes arachnids [spiders] and crustaceans [crabs, lobsters, etc.].)

Comment: Not just language, certainly not limited to the English language at all, the answer would fall properly in the domain of taxonomy. Note that taxonomy is a science in its own right.

Comment: Don’t know how tell you this, but insects happen to be animals.  So the answer is still *megafauna*.

Answer (score 1):

*Flora* and *fauna* are Latin terms that we currently use to represent plants and wildlife.

The Latin word for *insect* is *insectum* (borrowed from a Greek word that meant "to cut into sections").  So my guess would be ***Megainsectum***.

Comment: +1 As a family/ higher level, it would be the plural *megainsect **a***, though.